# Cursor moving to last line when pressing Ctrl + s in Visual Studio Code in .js file. I have tried keeping Auto Save On and Off but problem persist

Tags: visual-studio-code

Cursor moving to last line when pressing Ctrl + s in Visual Studio Code in .js file. I have tried keeping Auto Save On and Off but problem persist.
How can I turn off this issue?

Comment: I would start by searching for the "Ctrl + s" hotkey in your Keyboard Shortcuts (File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts), and see if you have not accidentally linked it to a wrong command.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried disabling all extensions one by one, finally found that prettier extension update was causing this issue. I rolled back to previous version of this extension and now it is working absolutely fine.
Prettier is a code formatting extension.